# A question was marked as "duplicate" when in fact it wasn't

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I have absolutely no idea why [this question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/23026/why-was-france-given-such-a-lenient-peace-after-napoleon-was-defeated) was marked as "a duplicate". The supposedly duplicated question has absolutely nothing to do with the original question.

I put this as a comment but since it was drown in the middle of a huge flame war that also has strictly nothing to do with the OP's question, it is unlikely to ever be seen.

I suspect that the flaggers were part in the (unrelated) flame war in the comments. Since I cannot flag flags, I have no other option that put this on meta.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Eh, it was the OP that marked it as a duplicate. Their username is right there in the "marked as duplicate" notification.

Comment: @Yannis Oh you are correct. My god this makes absolutely *no* sense at all.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​My guess is that it's either a mistake, or a reaction to the discussion in the comments. In any case, voting to re-open...